# Forms in Django

Tags: django, django-forms

I have two models, a studen and an agent. because student model has some choice field, I'm using ModelForm for Form and that's great. Every Student has an agent:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    ncode = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    family = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    father = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    telephone = models.CharField(max_length=18, blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    reagent = models.ForeignKey(Reagent)
    state = models.IntegerField(choices=STUDYING_STATUS)
    degree = models.IntegerField(choices=DEGREE_STATUS)

class Reagent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    family = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    telephone = models.CharField(max_length=18)
```

These are forms:

```
class Student_Form(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Student

class Reagent_Form(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Reagent
```

But I planed to get both agent and student in one form so, I put them together in one form in template:

```
<form action="" method="POST"> {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
        {{ student_form.as_table}}
        {{ reagent_form.as_table }}
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Add">
</form>
```

**My problem is how can I get entered informations in separate instances of student and agent forms?**
if in template was just one forms info I would used **f = StudentForm(request.POST)**! But the forms are mixed in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still do

```
f = Student_Form(request.POST)
r = Reagent_Form(request.POST)
```

and django will assign the appropriate fields.

To hide the FK field,

```
class Student_Form(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        exclude = ('reagent', )

class Reagent_Form(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Reagent
```

While saving in the view,

```
def myview(request):
    reagent_form = Reagent_Form(prefix='reagent')
    student_form = Student_Form(prefix='student')
    if request.POST:            
         reagent_form = Reagent_Form(request.POST, prefix='reagent')
         student_form = Student_Form(request.POST, prefix='student')
         if reagent_form.is_valid() and student_form.is_valid():
             reagent = reagent_form.save() #first create the object
             student = student_form.save(commit=False) 
             student.reagent = reagent #then assign to student. 
             student.save()

         #rest of the code.
```

Comment: Ok thanks. Just one more question: because the relation between student and agent it shows a choise field for student to get agent. how can I hide that field from user?

Comment: Just edited the question. This could cause an issue with `name` field, so use a `prefix="student"` or `prefix="reagent"`  while creating the forms - that way names are not conflicted.

Comment: Note that if you create the two forms and render them in the same template, you'll need to use a `prefix` argument for one of them to avoid collisions on the `name`, `family` and `telephone` fields which they share.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#prefixes-for-forms

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm creating a windows app with Django instead of .Net and I think this 100 times better and I will achieve better application.

Comment: IMHO, you will be very happy with the switch :)